# Whitelisting an IP address on GoDaddy hosting

Tags: mysql

I realize that this is probably not the best place to ask this question, but GoDaddy is far more than useless and has one of the crappiest layouts ive seen. I am trying to access my mysql database remotely from a python script I am writing. I cannot find where to whitelist my ip address so I can connect and their online help chat is offline + the phones are not working. I remember having this problem a few months ago and there was an insanely obscure and hidden link for this that took the tech rep over an hour to find. I have been searching for awhile and cannot find anything helpful at all.

Comment: I think if you could make a tunnel that would be smart as it's highly not recommended to connect to the Database directly "from outside". You can find some instructions here: https://mediatemple.net/community/products/dv/204403884/tunnel-local-mysql-server-through-ssh

Comment: @Axalix I don't think GoDaddy provide SSH by default...

Comment: @Ryan ya those links are pretty troll because there is no where to whitelist your ip so the connection will get denied if you try that.

Comment: I read that as well, but that is not an option when you create the database

Comment: All the godaddy links are wrong according to the rep I talked to briefly who then just left.

Comment: I am having the same problem and just asked a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56331074/connect-to-godaddy-server-database-from-localhost-computer). You need to purchase Website Security, is what I have concluded, in order to access these security features. Purchasing this can be found in your 'My Hosting' page on the GoDaddy website on your account.